# ¿Cómo puedo guardar en una variable char el valor de una tecla presionada?

Tags: dev-c++

recientemente vi que hay personas que guardan en una variable char la tecla que presionaron, tipo así: `char key = getch();`
y luego veo que usan una condición para ver si en verdad la presionó.
Bueno, básicamente quiero hacer eso pero presionando la tecla "1" y que detecte si se presiono

Comment: Y que has intentado?

Comment: Si no agregas algo que demuestre que eres parte del esfuerzo por responder tu propia duda, tu pregunta podría terminar cerrada. Lecturas recomendadas: [¿Cómo preguntar?](/help/how-to-ask) y [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)

Comment: perdón, he descubiero que para eso se hace algo así

Comment: char key = getch();

Comment: char key = getch(); if(key == '1'){//cuerpo}